# Set operations unsupported in dafny

Tags: dafny

I am new in dafny and I encountered a problem when working with a set like this one:
`var myset : set<(int, int)> := {(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 20)};`

1. How can I get first pair into a variable? And then how can I access each value inside this pair?
2. How can I add a pair to my myset ?

For arrays is working in this way : `myarray[i].0` and `myarray[i].1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets are immutable, unordered collections.

1. There is no such thing as the "first" element of the set. You can choose an arbitrary element like this:

   ```
   var x :| x in myset;  // get an arbitrary element
   ```

   `x` is guaranteed to be *an* element of the set, but you don't know which one. For example, Dafny verifies the following assertion about `x`:

   ```
   assert x == (1,10) || x == (2, 20) || x == (3, 20);
   ```
2. To add an element, you can use `+` (and variable assignment):

   ```
   myset := myset + {(4, 0)}; // add an element
   ```